# How do you cycle the active inventory row?

Tags: stardew-valley

I started playing this with a steam controller. When playing with that controller you could hit the R/L back trigger (under bumper? not the trigger and not the bumper) and cycle the active row of inventory. Convenient way to switch between a weapon and a pick for instance.

Now I'm on a new computer and trying to bind the steam controller correctly. Or set up a brand new "just right for me" controller config.

I can't figure out what key actually does this. It's not on the wiki and I can't find it in any steam discussions.

Comment: Are you asking about default keyboard + mouse controls?

Comment: Yes. There is a way to cycle those rows but it's not listed on the wiki. Or in the game. But you can do it with a steam controller.

Comment: It can be done with a Steam controller and "Gamepad with camera controls" scheme. The right/left bumper buttons will cycle the active tool row. But the HUD mode won't show me what button that is. The keycodes are 17 and 18.

Comment: however I couldn't get the inventory rows to cycle with the corresponding keyboard keys (Ctrl or Alt IIRC)

Comment: On the Nintendo Switch this feature is called "Shift Toolbar". On PC using keyboard and mouse there seems to be no way to configure it at the moment, but someone made a mod: https://github.com/Pathoschild/StardewMods/blob/stable/RotateToolbar/README.md

Comment: tab key works with vanilla version now

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it is not possible on keyboard (bug?) and can only be configured using a controller.
There is [a mod on Nexus](https://www.nexusmods.com/stardewvalley/mods/1100/?) which allows you to do this by using (by default) the <kbd>tab</kbd> key. The key is configurable!

Here is an image of how it works (from the mod page):
[image]

Comment: tab key works with vanilla version now